# Execute multiple statements from same parameters using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've just been writing a function that checks multiple tables to find if we've got at least one record  for each of the tables, which ends up in the following code:

```
$foo1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = ? LIMIT 1");
$foo2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE column2 = ? LIMIT 1");
$foo1->execute(array( $foo3 ));
$foo2->execute(array( $foo3 ));
$foo1 = $foo1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$foo2 = $foo2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Is there a way to improve this so that you can execute/fetch just once?
$foo4 is exactly the same throughout each of the queries.

Comment: sure, use an `AND` or an `OR` and a JOIN

Comment: @Fred-ii- maybe `UNION`?

Comment: @u_mulder sure, that too (I edited my comment before seeing your ping) *btw* ;-)

Comment: So you're suggesting: http://pastebin.com/2vL4hB9b - this just seems to return an array with one item, even though there are things in three tables (should be ':bar' => $foo3, just error in example)